# Versionar dados gravados no Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Toda configuração que tenho no Jenkins hoje, bem como usuários, senhas, configurações de CI/CD e todo o aparato necessários para meus projetos será perdido se eu precisar iniciar uma nova instalação do Jenkins. Como posso versionar essa estrutura de arquivos para futuras instalações do Jenkins ou até mesmo compartilhando facilitado entre a equipe de trabalho? Alguém tem uma sugestão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oi! Você pode salvar as configurações e Jobs com o [thinBackup plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=49512461#content/view/49512461). 
Se estiver trabalhando com infraestrutura ágil, recomendo o [Jenkins Configuration as Code](https://jenkins.io/projects/jcasc/).

Comment: Esses plugins fazem bkp das configurações do Jenkins? Como credenciais configuradas, regras de instalações e etc.

Comment: Sim. Com o thinBackup você pode fazer o backup de suas configurações (mais 'enxuto')  Se precisar fazer backup de absolutamente tudo (JENKINS_HOME), use o [Backup  Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/backup).